# equivalent of double in stdint.h?

Tags: c, stdint

I am trying to figure out my way through c89 and now I ma stuck with this problem.
Does `stdint.h` have any equivalent for double data type? 
If yes how do we print it?

Comment: Are you asking for where to find `FLT_MAX` and friends? You can turn to `float.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdint.h` is for integer types and there is no fixed-size floating types in C.

By the way you are mentioning C89, note that `stdint.h` standard header is a C99 addition.

Comment: I had a function which use bool and when I compiled it it gave the error that bool is not supported. So I assumed that gcc is compiling by default with c89 standard. I do not know but I am able to compile the `stdint.h` header with the same compiler which does not compiles `bool` keyword.

Comment: `gcc` compiles in C89 with GNU extensions by default. To use `bool`, include `stdbool.h` and compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` (C99 with GNU extensions).

Comment: `bool` is a C99 construct. What version of gcc are you using? Note that you can specify the standard compliance via `-std=c99` just to be sure.

Comment: @ouah you missed my point. I was saying that if `stdint.h` would have been a c99 construct that why is not gcc compiling bool. I mean to point at the contradiction between these two facts.

Comment: it IS a c99 addition. `gcc` is just kind enough to let you include the header in c89 without complaining.

Comment: may be an so I assumed I am working on c89. I would like to ask that will it include the functionality of that header or it is just not complaining. I mean my code largely depends on keywords like `unit8_t`.